# What is the correct input shape for my LSTM network?

Tags: neural-networks, tensorflow, keras, recurrent-neural-networks, long-short-term-memory

My professor gave us a workshop where we have to do classification of a dataset of ECG signals between healthy and unhealthy types using LSTM. Each signal consists of 1,285 time steps.

What my prof did was to cut up each signal into segments 24 time steps long, advancing 6 steps for the next segment. In other words, for the following signal

```
0, 1, 2, ... 1283, 1284, 1285
```

It will be cut up into the following segments

```
0, 1, 2, ... 21, 22, 23
6, 7, 8, ... 27, 28, 29
12, 13, 14, ... 33, 34, 35
...
```

These segments are the input to the LSTM model for each signal to be classified.

Using the code that my prof used to cut the signal into segments, and feeding that into Tensorflow-Keras InputLayer, it tells me that the output shape is `(None, 211, 24)`.

However, I am told by a classmate that the correct implementation for Tensorflow-Keras LSTM should be `(None, 24, 211)`. He tried clarifying with the prof but it seems the prof doesn't really understand what my classmate's trying to say. I tried to Google but examples I can find online are either of the two cases below:

- The format of an input signal should be `(None, # timesteps, # features)`. However, in my problem the signal only has one feature that is chopped up into segments. In this example I found online, there's no mention of segments.
- The only example of signals being cut into segments I can find is when each segment is a single input. That is not the case for me. My input is a single signal, cut up into 211 segments which collectively make up a single input.

Which is the correct output shape for my LSTM model? My prof used his method and achieved 96% classification accuracy, and our assignment is to surpass that rate, but when I tested using what my classmate said is the correct shape, my LSTM model with the exact same architecture, hyperparameters etc. gave me a flat 74.04% accuracy from the 1st epoch all the way to the end without ever changing. So which is wrong?